# Sobre licencias y el historial de commits

Tags: licencias

acabo de publicar un repositorio en Github. En el último commit (el quinto) añadí la licencia.

Entonces hasta ese commit el repositorio no tenía licencia, aunque tampoco era público, cosa que no queda registrada en el propio software, entonces:

Si se clona un repositorio y se elimina el commit donde se introdujo la licencia (y posteriores en su caso), ¿ese código queda sin licencia ya que el código anterior no la tenía?

¿Esto varía según si el código fue hecho público antes o después de añadir la misma?

Answer (score 2):

> intentaré responder a tu pregunta lo mejor posible. La licencia de tu
>   código cumple la función a partir de que la agregues a tu repositorio,
>   si tú agregaste tu licencia hoy, todo tu código a partir de hoy, sin
>   importar cuando lo escribiste pasa a estar cubierto por la licencia,
>   cualquier descarga, branch, o utilización de tu código debe cumplir
>   con dicha licencia, y es denunciable o reportable su mal uso o nulo
>   respeto, un saludo!